# ASIHTTPRequest does not fetch data, It calls only fail method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to integrate Facebook in iOS app. I have done authentication properly. I am using Raywenderlich's code. I was trying to execute that code. But I get error. When i try to fetch the user's profile using the access token ,it does not fetch it. Rather it calls the fail method. I've tried in many sites but i am not able to solve this problem.

I have this doubt, In the following method, my print the url in the log. when copy that url and paste it in the browser and run it. It gives the json data. but in the code it  does not fetch. it always called failed method.

Here is my code.

```
- (void) getFacebookProfile {
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",[_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"profile UrlString: %@", urlString);

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


    ASIHTTPRequest * request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookProfileFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(getFacebookProfileFailed:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
    request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;

    [request startAsynchronous];



}


- (void) getFacebookProfileFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request {
    NSLog(@"profile information has failed");
    NSLog(@"%@", [request error]);    
}

- (void) getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
//somecode
}
```

This code always calls the fail method. In the fail method , i i have printed the error. The error is as follows

> Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure
>   occurred" UserInfo=0x94d47a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xa36b700 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)",
>   NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}

Comment: the error says it all. IS the url working outside of `ASIHttp` ? Is your internet connection working? I suspect the former.

Comment: Have you found any solutions ?